# Go to newline in android with HTMLViewer

Tags: android

I will store a data in a file.and  i will display it.But my problem is how can i control the HTMLVewr or other reader to go a newline.
in this code when i display the file "file1" there are no newline.

```
 try {
         FileOutputStream ops=openFileOutput("file1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(ops);

          for(int i=0;i<w*h;i++){
                //int alpa=Color.alpha(pixels[i]);
                int red=Color.red(pixels[i]);
                int green=Color.green(pixels[i]);
                int blue=Color.blue(pixels[i]);
                String k;
                if(i==0)
                    k=red+" "+green+" "+blue+" ";

                else if((i%(w-1)==0)&&(i>0)){

                   k="**"+red+" "+green+" "+blue+" ";
                   k=k+"/n";}
                else
                   k="**"+red+" "+green+" "+blue+" ";

                dos.write(k.getBytes());
                }

                 ops.close();


                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: If you do not add newlines than no viewer/editor can show them. What do you want exactly?

Comment: if i add newlines "/n" ,in my files i see "/n".and there are no go to the future line.Now i ask if it's possible to indicate to reader(viewer/editor) that,he has to go to the future line.

Comment: You have to add "\n" for a new line ;-). But this will not help using a html viewer. Better use a text editor to view the file and give your file a .txt extension.

Comment: Sorry. Don't understand what you said/wanted.

Comment: ok ok i'm changing "/n" to "\n" and problem solved :)